# WiFi driver issues in ASUS ROG G15 (2021)

Tags: wireless, asus

I decided to shift to Ubuntu from Debian after getting my new laptop because of Nvidia driver issues in Debian(now I understand Linus Torvald's frustration ).

***lspci | grep Network*** gave the following result: **Mediatek Corp. Device 7961**

I can't seem to find the drivers anywhere. I'm runnung Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop, and I am running Ubuntu 21.04 as well.

The solution for the wireless is upgrading the kernel to an stable version higher than 5.12+. I am running:

```
Asus-ROG:~$ uname -r
5.13.5-051305-generic
```

After I upgraded the kernel started working for me.

NOTE: wifi is working fine, with good speed tests, nothing to report, issue I still have is the Bluetooth connection.

Good luck

Comment: Works like a charm, tested with Linux Mint 20.3