# Driver for Mediatek wifi card 7961

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus, mediatek

I'm not able to connect to wifi as i'm missing the driver for Mediatek wifi card 7961 in my asus scar laptop.
I searched for drivers for this chip online but couldn't find any .
Can anyone help/ suggest any compatible drivers ?

> lspci output : 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
> Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]

Thanks.

Comment: Update : I updated my linux kernal to 5.13 ( stable versions > 5.12 will do ) , and now, i can connect to wifi . Similar issue found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349097/wifi-driver-issues-in-asus-rog-g15-2021?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate: [Wifi not working on ASUS rog zephyrus g14 2021](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340800/wifi-not-working-on-asus-rog-zephyrus-g14-2021)

Seems people are solved this issue with upgrading their kernel to 5.12+

Comment: Yh I just updated linux kernel to 5.13.5 . It works now . Thanks.

Comment: You can choose this answer as accepted by clicking to tick if your problem is solved. Glad that works. @JithinThomas